# How to display Sunset time for local time zone using swift 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, swift4

How can i display Sunset time for local time zone using swift 4?

I have Text label. I want to replace the label text with sunset time.

Answer (score 1):

Add the **EDSunriseSet cocoa-pod** to your project, and use it like this :

```
var sunInfo = EDSunriseSet.sunriseset(withTimezone: timeZone, latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
```

and then call the following methods, based on your requirements:

```
sunInfo.calculateTwilight(Date())
sunInfo.calculateSunriseSunset(Date())
```

For more information, you can refer the article : 
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/09/ios-sunrise-sunset-corelocation/